# Signaling with shared objects

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not able to understand, where to place methods

hasDataToProcess() & setHasDataToProcess() of MySignal class,

in App9 class to maintain synchronization on object of type NotThreadSafe.

Please help me the know the place !!!

//Signalling via shared objects

### Code:

```
class MySignal{
    protected boolean hasDataToProcess = false;

    public synchronized boolean hasDataToProcess(){
        return this.hasDataToProcess;
    }
    public synchronized void setHasDataToProcess(boolean hasData){
        this.hasDataToProcess = true;
    }
}

class NotThreadSafe{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    public void add(String text){
        this.builder.append(text);
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
}

public class App9 extends Thread {
    NotThreadSafe instance;
    protected MySignal sharedSignal = new MySignal();
    public App9(NotThreadSafe sharedInstance){
        this.instance = sharedInstance;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        this.instance.add("sham");
        this.instance.display();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NotThreadSafe sharedInstance = new NotThreadSafe();
        for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
            Thread t = new App9(sharedInstance);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `run()` method?

Comment: Your `MySignal` now as it stands can be replaced with a `volatile boolean`.  What is supposed to do?  I see no locking or anything that's going to help protect your `NotThreadSafe` class.

Comment: my goal is to to perform synchronization on NotThreadSafe object with busy wait. something like.. protected MySignal sharedSignal=...;while(!sharedSignal.hasDataToProcess()){//do nothing .. busy waiting}